# Showing image in SELECT element

Tags: html

For example:

```
<code>
<select>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>
</code>
```

I want to use some image in place of 1, 2 or 3. But looks like it is not working. You Geek people, help me out of this, how can I do that? Is there any alternative solution you can provide?

thanks

Comment: hey man...I didn't mean to hurt people...I meant you are technically expert... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're asking isn't possible using "straight" HTML - you'd need to use JavaScript, ideally a library such as the popular [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), which quite possibly has a [plug-in](http://plugins.jquery.com/) that already does this.

As a (random) example, see http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown

Comment: Can you provide a simple example for that or point to the exact page of jquery in the web?

Comment: @Masud I've updated my answer with an example, but there are most likely others. Hope this helps. :-)